# Quick Sort not working at 10k elements

Tags: c++, quicksort

My teacher gave me a quick sort function to use and test execution times, but when it gets to a 10,000 element list it throws a stack overflow and I can't figure out why. I've tested it on several different computers with the same result at around 9375 out of 10,000 elements parsed through.

The quicksort file

```
#include "swap.h"

/** Chooses a pivot for quicksort's partition algorithm and swaps
 *  it with the first item in an array.
 * @pre theArray[first..last] is an array; first <= last.
 * @post theArray[first] is the pivot.
 * @param theArray  The given array.
 * @param first  The first element to consider in theArray.
 * @param last  The last element to consider in theArray. */
void choosePivot(int theArray[], int first, int last){
    //cerr << "choosePivot(array, " << first << ", " << last << ")\n";
    int mid = (last - first) / 2;
    if( (theArray[first] <= theArray[mid] &&
         theArray[mid] <= theArray[last]) ||
        (theArray[last] <= theArray[mid] &&
         theArray[mid] <= theArray[first]) ){
        // value at mid index is middle of values at first and last indices 
        swap(theArray[first], theArray[mid]);
    }else if( (theArray[first] <= theArray[last] &&
               theArray[last] <= theArray[mid]) ||
              (theArray[mid] <= theArray[last] &&
               theArray[last] <= theArray[first])){
        // value at last index is middle of values
        swap(theArray[first], theArray[last]);
    }
}


/** Partitions an array for quicksort.
 * @pre theArray[first..last] is an array; first <= last.
 * @post Partitions theArray[first..last] such that:
 *    S1 = theArray[first..pivotIndex-1] <  pivot
 *         theArray[pivotIndex]          == pivot
 *    S2 = theArray[pivotIndex+1..last]  >= pivot
 * @param theArray  The given array.
 * @param first  The first element to consider in theArray.
 * @param last  The last element to consider in theArray.
 * @param pivotIndex  The index of the pivot after partitioning. */
void partition(int theArray[],
               int first, int last, int& pivotIndex){
   // place pivot in theArray[first]
   choosePivot(theArray, first, last);
   int pivot = theArray[first];     // copy pivot

   // initially, everything but pivot is in unknown
   int lastS1 = first;           // index of last item in S1
   int firstUnknown = first + 1; // index of first item in
                                 // unknown

   // move one item at a time until unknown region is empty
   for (; firstUnknown <= last; ++firstUnknown)
   {  // Invariant: theArray[first+1..lastS1] < pivot
      //         theArray[lastS1+1..firstUnknown-1] >= pivot

      // move item from unknown to proper region
      if (theArray[firstUnknown] < pivot)
      {  // item from unknown belongs in S1
         ++lastS1;
         swap(theArray[firstUnknown], theArray[lastS1]);
      }  // end if

      // else item from unknown belongs in S2
   }  // end for

   // place pivot in proper position and mark its location
   swap(theArray[first], theArray[lastS1]);
   pivotIndex = lastS1;
}  // end partition

/** sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
 * @pre theArray[first..last] is an array.
 * @post theArray[first..last] is sorted.
 * @param theArray  The given array.
 * @param first  The first element to consider in theArray.
 * @param last  The last element to consider in theArray. */
void quicksort(int theArray[], int first, int last){
    int pivotIndex;

   if (first < last)
   {  // create the partition: S1, pivot, S2
      partition(theArray, first, last, pivotIndex);

      // sort regions S1 and S2
      quicksort(theArray, first, pivotIndex-1);
      quicksort(theArray, pivotIndex+1, last);
   }  // end if
}  // end quicksort
```

The swap.h file

```
#ifndef _SWAP_H
#define _SWAP_H

/** Swaps two items.
 * @pre x and y are the items to be swapped.
 * @post Contents of actual locations that x and y represent are
 *       swapped.
 * @param x  Given data item.
 * @param y  Given data item. */
void swap(int& x, int& y){
   int temp = x;
   x = y;
   y = temp;
}  // end swap

#endif /* _SWAP_H */
```

And the implementation file

```
//main.cpp
//Angelo Todaro
//Main driverto clock the timing efficiency of different sort algorithms for different sized lists

#include "quickSort.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double diffclock(clock_t,clock_t);

int main(){
    clock_t begin, end;//clocks to store number of ticks at beginning and end
    srand(time(NULL));//initialize seed
    cout << "# of Elements\tQuick\n";
    for(int n = 10; n < 100000; n*=10){
        int* array = new int[n];
        cout << n << "\t\t";
        for(int i =0; i < n; i++){
            array[i]=rand()%1000;
        }


        //quick sort
        begin=clock();
        quicksort(array,0,n);
        end=clock();
        cout << diffclock(end,begin) << "\t";

    }

    return 0;
}


double diffclock(clock_t clock1, clock_t clock2){
    double diffticks = clock1-clock2;//finds difference between ticks
    double diffmili=diffticks/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;//turns tickes into miliseconds
    return diffmili;
}
```

Comment: you never delete the allocated memory.

Comment: You forgot to do `delete array` at the end of your main loop. By the time you create your 10,000 element array, you've got 1110 elements already allocated. This won't help you get to 100,000, though.

Comment: @cmh look at the for loop iteration step. `n*=10`.

Comment: @todaroa: [Always check accuracy before doing big tests](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=599e0c512a09b2a237e315eb791cb2ff), your code fails when given `{0,0,1}`.  Error probably has nothing to do with the number of elements.

Comment: I don't get any errors running this code, even up to 10000000 elements. Note that since your condition is `n < 100000`, it only goes up to 10000 elements. Are you sure the error isn't elsewhere?

Comment: @Todaroa: found the bug: your `choosePivot` function reads and then swaps with `theArray[last]` which is outside of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive quicksort implementation that also does not choose a very good pivot. Given some inputs it may make a function call for every single element. 10k calls on the stack is pretty hard to handle. At this point only an iterative inplace quicksort with random pivot would be a good algorithm.

Comment: It's not 10k calls on the stack, it's approximately `log2(10000)` calls which about 14.

Comment: @DavidBrown I believe theoretical absolute worst case, it could make 10k calls on the stack.

Comment: @DavidBrown That is incorrect. Given the code it is possible to construct input such that it will recurse for every single element by choose a bad pivot (such as always the first element).

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I asked my teacher and they said that it should have no problem, but I've heard several people in the class have had the same problem as me.

Comment: @DavidBrown: if you do the math, 10k elements averages a depth of like 22 calls.

Comment: Given there are only 1000 possible distinct values, the pathological case should only be 1000 calls on the stack.

Comment: @cmh: only if you optimize the quicksort to notice duplicates of the pivot.  Most implementations I've seen don't do that.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: (1) I seriously doubt most people can code an iterative inplace quicksort. (2) The bug is because he reads past the end of the array.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Without any knowledge about the data that has to be sorted using the first value as pivot is as good as using a random element as pivot.

Comment: @mikyra except I have knowledge of the data, namely that within computer memory, sorted data is more common than other arbitrary orders: Because programmers like to sort things, and we leave data all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

When I [debugged your code](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7650d51cda8d39f85eb273755dad49c3) for you, I can see that when you call `choosePivot`, and there's only one element, it's being *erased entirely*:

```
enter quicksort(array, 2, 3)
1  //content of region
enter partition(array, 2, 3)
1  //content of region 
enter choosePivot(array, 2, 3)
1  //content of region 
0  //content of region - WAIT, WHAT HAPPENED TO THE ONE
end choosePivot
0   //content of region
end partition
```

so we've found at least the location of the problem: `choosePivot`.  When we look at that function carefully, I eventually realized the error:

```
void choosePivot(int theArray[], int first, int last){
    //cerr << "enter choosePivot(array, " << first << ", " << last << ")\n";
    int mid = (last - first) / 2;
    if( (theArray[first] <= theArray[mid] &&
         theArray[mid] <= theArray[last]) ||
        (theArray[last] <= theArray[mid] &&
         theArray[mid] <= theArray[first]) ){
```

`theArray[last]` is OUT OF BOUNDS and PAST THE END OF THE ARRAY.  You swapped a completely random and invalid number into the array, and one of your elements out of the array.  This appears to happen quite frequently actually.  This is why we test for accuracy before we test with large numbers.

When I changed `theArray[last]` to `theArray[last-1]`, your code [passes all of my tests](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=84155a029c6d26d74eefcad9dd021316).  Note:

- The C++ library already has `std::swap`.
- You leak all your memory.  Match `delete` with `new` or better yet, use `std::vector<int>`.